# How can I prevent two jobs running at the same time with database locks?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

Assuming I've a `Job` table with data like `id, start_date, start_time, status`. A job should not be able to start if there's any other job in a non-final state.
So it could happen that two requests `SELECT` at the same time, see no data, and `INSERT` with a new generated id.

Is `Serializable` enough here to prevent the second `SELECT` from happening until after the first transaction is finished? Or how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Serializable will not block.  It will let both jobs run, then one of them gets thrown an error when it tries to commit.  That is probably not desirable.

You could use an advisory lock in which all job runners agree on what integers to use to identify their job.  Then they take the advisory lock when they start, and release it when they enter the "final state", whatever that is.